# How to configure a Git commit template for the repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to modify the default template for the commit message in Git. But till now I was not able to find a way how to do it globally for the whole repo. I only found possibilities to do it locally via `git config`.

Is there a way to modify the general commit template somehow? I am hosting the repo in my own Gitlab.

Comment: `git config` can be either global (for all repos on your computer) or for one (whole) repo.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have expressed myself in a misleading way. I want to set the template for the repo so that everyone who checks out this repo can see my changed template. But the longer I think about it, the more I realise that this is not possible, because presumably the default template is simply managed in the client itself and has nothing to do with the repo, right?

Comment: It has everything to do with the repo. It has nothing to do with any particular *history* that might have been fetched into that repo, nor with however any repos it fetched that history from were configured.  If you want to provide some suggested configs, provide them. If you want to mandate that people use those configs, Git does not convey authority. If you already have the authority to mandate that people use those configs, use that authority. Git can't grant you that authority.

Comment: Get everyone to put a [`commit-msg` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_commit_msg) in `.git/hooks`. You can tell people to do this in your `README`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will think about it what will be the best way for my purpose.

Comment: If, for instance, you have administrative control of the Git install on those computers, you can set the system-default template repo to have that config item preloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some internal discussion and will solve the problem as follows: Users will be trained/instructed on what the commit message should look like, specifically that a ticket number must be included. If this is not sufficient, I will set up a corresponding hook script.

As a small side note: It is interesting to see how individual IDEs and Git parameters handle it when the message starts with a #.

Answer (score 1):

There are several [ways](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html) to configure commit message template globally:

1. [Configure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html#validate-commit-messages) push rules for commit message validation. This approach requires `Premium` or `Ultimate` [subscription level](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/).
2. [Create](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#Enforcing-a-Specific-Commit-Message-Format) git server hook for commit message validation and [set](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#set-server-hooks-for-a-repository) it in GitLab server. This approach requires access to GitLab server file system.

You have to have administrator rights for all of them.

Also it is possible to configure push rules [per project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html#override-global-push-rules-per-project) without administrator rights, but still you must have `Premium` or `Ultimate` subscription level.